# Install VSIX package created in Visual Studio 2015 on VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

We have built a VSIX package that we built and use in Visual Studio 2015. We still have some projects (SQL Data Projects) that we can't upgrade to 2015, so we want to install the package in 2013. Is there a way that we can get the current package to run on Visual Studio 2013?

The VSIX installer only gives the option to install in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I went with an easy option of installing the 2013 SDK and making a project there. The 2013 project works in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. That'll do for what we needed.